# Transfer function of Lag-Lead Passive Filter

Tags: passive-filter

According to a book, transfer function of the lag-lead filter below is expressed as:

$$\operatorname{F}(s)=\frac{s {T_2} +1}{s {T_1} \, \left( s {T_3} +1\right) }$$

there,
$${T_1}={C_1} \left( {R_1}+{R_2}\right) $$
$${T_2}=\left( {C_1}+{C_2}\right)  {R_2}$$
$${T_3}={C_2} {R_2}$$

…(1)

[image]

But my calculations give different results.
Please advise what is wrong.

Impedance of the area indicated by the dashed line
1/(s*C_1)+(R_2 + 1/(s*C_1)) …(2)

So the transfer function of the filter is
$$\frac{\left( {C_1}+{C_2}\right)  {R_2} s+1}{{C_1} {C_2} {R_1} {R_2} {{s}^{2}}+\left( \left( {C_1}+{C_2}\right)  {R_2}+{C_1} {R_1}\right)  s+1}$$

Unfortunately the denominator expression does not match eq(1).

Comment: The denominator of the function (first line) must be wrong. For w=0 the expression gives a gain approaching infinite. This is obviously wrong (the "1" is missing).

Comment: What was the schematic given in the book ?

Comment: TF is output impedance divided by input impedance. This is \$\frac{Z}{R+Z}\$, where Z is your highlighted impedance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, notice the following: the transfer function of the circuit:

[image: schematic]

Is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}:=\frac{\text{v}_\text{o}}{\text{v}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag1$$

You can show that using the voltage divider formula.

So, for your case, we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\frac{\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}+\left(\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}+\left(\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\right)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2\text{R}_2+1}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2\text{R}_2+1}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1+\frac{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2\text{R}_2+1}}{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}_1\text{R}_1+\frac{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2\text{R}_2+1}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2\text{R}_2+1+\text{sC}_1\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\left(\text{sC}_2\text{R}_2+1\right)\left(1+\text{sC}_1\text{R}_1\right)+\text{sC}_1\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2\text{R}_2+1+\text{sC}_1\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle1+\text{s}\text{C}_1\text{R}_1+\text{s}\text{C}_2\text{R}_2+\text{s}^2\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{sC}_1\text{R}_2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)\text{s}+1}{\displaystyle\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{s}^2+\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)\right)\text{s}+1}
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

So, for the absolute value, we get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{1+\left(\text{R}_2\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)\omega\right)^2}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\omega^2\right)^2+\left(\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)\right)\omega\right)^2}}\tag3$$

For the argument, we can first set \$\displaystyle\alpha:=1-\text{C}_1\text{C}_2\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\omega^2\$ and \$\displaystyle\beta:=\left(\text{C}_1\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)\right)\omega\$, so we get:

$$
\arg\left(\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\displaystyle\arctan\left(\text{R}_2\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)\omega\right)-\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}&\space\text{if}\space\displaystyle\alpha=0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\displaystyle\arctan\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\displaystyle\alpha>0\space\wedge\space\beta>0\\
\\
\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\left|\alpha\right|}{\beta}\right)&\space\text{if}\space\displaystyle\alpha<0\space\wedge\space\beta>0
\end{cases}\tag4
$$